# Get correct row count of DML statement in snowflake from history table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need row count of DML statements (insert,delete,update) in snowflake. 'row_produced' from information_schema.query_history() table is not showing the correct count of processed rows. Is there any other way to get the processed row count?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the produced rows from the Profile tab on the Snowflake History page.

Profile Overview section has the 'Total Statistics' tab that will display the rows affected.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile.html#how-to-access-query-profile